# creating idhttpserver with ssl encryption

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl, delphi-xe2

I am not good with delphi yet, but based on some examples I have managed to create simple http server with no more than 10 users.
There are 2 main problems I don't know how to solve yet.

1. proper way to authenticate, manage users - sessions
2. main problem, connection must be secure, so SSL encryption is needed, how to implement it?

Any example I found in relation with idhttpserver and openssl, was not quite complete or with older version of Indy.

I am currently working with Delphi XE2 with Indy 10 components.

Comment: Newer versions of Indy can be downloaded from the Indy project repository at http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/download/svn.en.aspx (XE2 is rather old so the new Indy version includes lots of bug fixes and improvements)

Comment: well, I will be stuck to XE2 for a while. Surprisingly, when I visited your given address to indyproject, I decided to revisit the old good forum. reading an openssl handler related problem, I noticed-guessed that I did follow some another example too blindly by adding wrongly some VerifyMode params. so somehow i did get ssl mode runing eh ... probably should rewrite question

Comment: @mjn: don't forget http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.aspx, which has important installation notes. For XE2 in particular: "*an erroneous dependancy on Indy has been identified in Embarcadero's dclnet160.bpl package.  Installing a new version of Indy will cause this package to fail to load correctly in the IDE, preventing all contained components (such as THTTPRIO, TXMLDocument, TWeb\*Dispatcher, T\*Producer, TTcp\*, TUdp\*), as well as Wizards and Property Editors for them, from appearing at design-time.*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> proper way to authenticate, manage users - sessions

`TIdHTTPServer` manages HTTP sessions for you if you set the `TIdHTTPServer.SessionState` property is true (it is false by default).  `TIdHTTPServer` uses cookies for session management, so your clients need to have cookies enabled.

Authentication has to be performed manually, but how you do that depends on whether your clients are using HTTP-based or HTML-based authentication.

For HTTP authentication, there are `ARequestInfo.UserName` and `ARequestInfo.Password` properties available.  If not valid, send an appropriate 401 response back to the client (if you set the `AResponseInfo.AuthRealm` property to a non-blank string, `TIdHTTPServer` will send a 401 response for you).  By default, `TIdHTTPServer` only supports `BASIC` authentication.  If you want to support other authentication schemes, you will have to use the `TIdHTTPServer.OnParseAuthentication` event, and send the 401 reply manually so you can send back appropriate `WWW-Authenticate` headers.  Either way, if the client is validated, you can use HTTP sessions to keep the client logged in between requests.  The `AResponseInfo.Session` and `AResponseInfo.Session` properties point at the current session.  If `TIdHTTPServer.AutoStartSession` is true (it is false by default), `TIdHTTPServer` creates new sessions automatically.  Otherwise, you can call `TIdHTTPServer.CreateSession()` yourself when needed.  `TIdHTTPSession` has a `Content` property that you can store session-specific data in. Or you can derive a new class from `TIdHTTPSession` and then use the `TIdHTTPServer.OnCreateSession` event to create instances of that class.

For HTML authentication, you have two choices, depending on how you configure your HTML:

1. if your HTML `<form>` tag does not have an `enctype` attribute, or it is set to `application/x-www-webform-urlencoded`, `TIdHTTPServer` will store the raw webform data in the `ARequestInfo.FormParams` property, and if `TIdHTTPServer.ParseParams` is true (which it is by default), the data will also be parsed into the `ARequestInfo.Params` property for you.
2. if your HTML `<form>` tag has an `enctype` attribute set to `multipart/form-data`, you will have to parse the content of the `ARequestInfo.PostStream` manually, as `TIdHTTPServer` does not yet parse that data for you (examples have been posted many times before on many different forums on how to parse that data manually using Indy's `TIdMessageDecoderMIME` class).  By default, `ARequestInfo.PostStream` points at a `TMemoryStream` object.  You can use the `TIdHTTPServer.OnCreatePostStream` event to create an instance of a different `TStream`-derived class, if desired.

> main problem, connection must be secure, so SSL encryption is needed, how to implement it?

Before activating the server:

1. assign a `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLBase`-derived component, such as `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL`, to the `TIdHTTPServer.IOHandler` property and configure it as needed (certificate, peer validation, SSL version(s), etc).  In the case of OpenSSL, you will have to deploy the 2 OpenSSL library binaries `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` (or non-Windows platform equivalents) with your app if they are not already pre-installed on the target OS, or if you want to ensure your app uses a specific version of OpenSSL.  At this time, OpenSSL is the only encryption that Indy supports natively, but there are third-party solutions available that are compatible with Indy, such as [EldoS SecureBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/).
2. fill in the `TIdHTTPServer.Binding` property with a binding for your desired HTTPS port (443 is the default HTTPS port).  Typically you should create 2 bindings, one for HTTP port 80 and one for HTTPS port 443.  Inside your `OnCommand...` handlers, if you receive a request that requires SSL/TLS encryption, you can check the port that the request was made on (`AContext.Binding.Port`) and if not HTTPS then redirect (`AResponseInfo.Redirect()`) the client to retry the request on the HTTPS port.
3. assign a handler to the `TIdHTTPServer.OnQuerySSLPort` event and have it set its `VUseSSL` parameter to True when its `APort` parameter matches your HTTPS port. **UPDATE** starting with SVN rev 5461, an `OnQuerySSLPort` handler [is no longer needed](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20180530.EN.aspx) if your only HTTPS port is 443.